# Fieldtype string vs strings

Tags: solr, solr6

I am having some confusion between the fieldtype available. `string` vs `strings` and `int` vs `ints` and the likes for other datatype.

What are the differences between the following 4?

```
<field name="string_multi" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="string_single" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="strings_multi" type="strings" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="strings_single" type="strings" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Given that I have document, what should I declare for my field named `hashtags`?

`String multivalued` or `strings multivalue` or `strings without multivalue`, ?

```
{
      "polarity":0.0,
      "text":"RT @socialistudents: Vlad - we go to NUS conference not just as individuals but as members of Socialist Students #SocStu17",
      "created_at":"Sun Feb 12 19:28:34 +0000 2017",
      "hashtags":[
         "hashtag1",
         "hashtag2"
      ],
      "subjectivity":0.0,
      "retweet_recount":4,
      "id":830861171582439424,
      "favorite_count":0
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you're talking about the default field types that are made when you use Solr's default schema, if you actually look at the fieldType definition it says this:

```
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" />
<fieldType name="strings" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true" docValues="true" />
```

**Edited**: The 2nd example should be `strings` instead of `string`

So they actually have the same class (solr's default string class `solr.StrField`) so they are the same type of data. The only difference is 'strings' is multivalued, which just means you can store multiple discrete values in the one field.

In your example, it seems that your hashtags data is just an array of individual hashtag values, so since you want to store multiple discrete strings in one field then 'strings' would be the choice as it is multiValued.

Comment: The confusion was when defining the `field name`. Whereby you can declare the attribute `multiValued` as such `<field name="your_field_name" type="strings" multiValued="true" sortMissingLast="true" docValues="true" indexed="false" required="true" stored="true"/>`. Well, they turn out to be the same. Just a little confusing and makes the `multiValued` during `field name` redundant. Since `multiValued` will be determined by the `field type`

Comment: Yes correct, sorry I missed the 's' on the second one. Fixed

Comment: Yeah you can declare 'multivalued' on the field as well. So given your hashtags data structure you can put `multiValued="true"` on your field definition